# How to setup azure communication services (email) with django

Tags: django, azure, djoser, azure-communication-services

I'm working on a django project where I want to send emails for account creation. Particularly, I am using djoser. I want to integrate azure communication services and their email service to send emails but I don't know how to do that. Can someone tell me how to use azure communication services in django and djoser.

I tried using the endpoint connection string and access keys as password but it did not work.